# Getting total amount in CI Cart Class?

Tags: codeigniter, cart, subtotal

I am using cart class `CI`, and inside i have subtotal. Is there way to count all subtotals and display them in view?

like `$total=$allsubtotal;`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Per the [Codeigniter Cart class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html):

> `$this->cart->total();`
>
> Displays the total amount in the cart.

Here's how it's calculated internally, in case you are curious:

```
/**
 * Cart Total
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function total()
{
    return $this->_cart_contents['cart_total'];
}
```

Here's where that is set:

```
/* snippet from function _save_cart */

// Lets add up the individual prices and set the cart sub-total
$total = 0;
$items = 0;
foreach ($this->_cart_contents as $key => $val)
{
    // We make sure the array contains the proper indexes
    if ( ! is_array($val) OR ! isset($val['price']) OR ! isset($val['qty']))
    {
        continue;
    }

    $total += ($val['price'] * $val['qty']);
    $items += $val['qty'];

    // Set the subtotal
    $this->_cart_contents[$key]['subtotal'] = ($this->_cart_contents[$key]['price'] * $this->_cart_contents[$key]['qty']);
}

// Set the cart total and total items.
$this->_cart_contents['total_items'] = $items;
$this->_cart_contents['cart_total'] = $total;
```

I'm not sure why `total`s return value is documented as an integer, should be a float/double.

Comment: CodeIgniter is a shame in PHP world :(